# I have an EC2 server that works with spring boot, need to have an ability to use https on public IPv4 endpoint requests, how can I do it?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

This problem is caused when we try to send request from our frontend (that live on GitHub pages) to backend on AQS and we find out that we can't use https on EC2. I already tried to manage it using Route 53 + Certificate Manager (where I get the certificate for my domain) + load balancer = as a result I have an https for this domain that have my EC2 in target group by I still can't send https directly on EC2 endpoints. What did I do wrong and how to fix this problem?

I need to have an ability to send https requests on my backend from GitHub.

Comment: What's the subnet configuration of your EC2 instance?

Comment: what do you need to know about subnet configuration?

Comment: Is it public/private? NACLs? Security group inbound rules?

Comment: The subnet is public with auto-assigned public IPv4 addresses. NACLs allow all inbound traffic but deny all traffic with a preference for the allow rule.Inbound rules: 100 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0 Allow
               * All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0 Deny

Comment: "i have an https for this domain that have my ec2 in target group by i still can't send https directly on ec2 endpoins" You will only have HTTPS at the load balancer DNS name, you will never be able to send HTTPS directly to the EC2 instance with this configuration. The whole point of the load balancer is that you would send all traffic *through* the load balancer.

Comment: thanks, I get it but we face the problem when the frontend sends requests directly on ec2 ipv4 and that's where we have the https problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with this. You mentioned a load balancer. I would put a static HTML page on your server with an nginx running to serve the page. Then I'd do the AWS magic to be able to load the page.

Once you do that, there's more simple nginx magic to redirect activity based on the URL. Or you can repoint the LB to point to your app instead of nginx.

As long as your instance (EC2 or container) has something running on the expected port (80 or whatever), all your config is in the LB.